How does kafka use write-behind?
From what I understand kafka uses the "write-behind" technique, when writing data. Meaning that it will write data to the page cache (as dirty pages) first and eventually flush these dirty pages to disk.
When does this flush occur? Does it happen before I receive an ack from kafka? If not, then there's no proper  fault tolerance imo, as we can lose data that is still in RAM and hasn't been flushed.

There are two broker properties which controls the flush in Kafka.
1.log.flush.interval.messages - The number of messages accumulated on a log partition before messages are flushed to disk.
2.log.flush.interval.ms - The maximum time in ms that a message in any topic is kept in memory before flushed to disk. If not set, the value in log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms is used.
Kafka recommends you not to change this properties.
Also Kafka depends on file system page cache.Kafka doesn't create its own in-memory messages,internally it uses file-system.Therefore in case of crash Kafka looses messages which are not yet flushed.

Thanks! It seems like it's better to deploy kafka in multi-az, otherwise there will be potential data loss if the entire az loses electricity.

yes,your right.
